# How can I pass a loaded image to another Matlab file using pushbutton?

Tags: image, matlab

After loading an image into a Matlab GUI, how can I pass that image using `pushbutton` to another Matlab file? When I push the button in my GUI, the image should be passed to my Matlab code.

Here is my GUI code

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
[filename,pathname]=uigetfile(...
{'*.jpg;*.gif;*.png;*.bmp',...
'image file(*.jpg,*.gif,*.png,*.bmp)';'*.*','all files(*.*)'},...
'open the image file to be verified');
fullimagefilename = fullfile(pathname,filename);
axes1 = imread(fullimagefilename);
axes(handles.axes1);
image(axes1);

%axes(handles.axes1);
%imshow('E:\degraded images\3.jpg')


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

    -pushbutton 1 is used to browse file .
    -and by pushbutton2 i want to pass the browsed file to my base file and its code is

im=imread('E:\degraded images\3.jpg'); 
hsv = rgb2hsv(im);
hueImage = hsv(:,:, 1);
meanHue = mean2(hueImage); 
figure, imshow(im);
title(meanHue);
%figure , imshow(im);
%im = imresize(im, 0.5);
%im2 = imread('E:\degraded images\3.jpg') ;
im2= im;
im=im(:,:,1);


sigmaA=8;
sigmaB=10;
sigmaMax=max([sigmaA sigmaB]);
fsz=[sigmaMax, sigmaMax];
```

Comment: size of image is known by size command. but i wan t to use x cordinate and number of rows seperately . how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the GUI uses `pushbutton1` to allow the user to choose a file and display it in the axes.  When the user presses the other button, `pushbutton2`, which is presumably on the same GUI, you want the callback for that button to have access to the selected (or browsed) image.

This can be done by creating a field in the `handles` structure for the selected image data, then storing this data using the `guidata` function.

In your first callback, do something like the following

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

[filename,pathname]=uigetfile(...
    {'*.jpg;*.gif;*.png;*.bmp',...
     'image file(*.jpg,*.gif,*.png,*.bmp)';'*.*','all files(*.*)'},...
     'open the image file to be verified');

% need to handle the case where the user presses cancel
if filename~=0
    fullimagefilename = fullfile(pathname,filename);

    % create an img field in handles for the image that is being loaded
    handles.img = imread(fullimagefilename);

    axes(handles.axes1);
    image(handles.img);

    % save the application data
    guidata(hObject,handles);
end
```

Now in your second callback, you can access this file through the `handles` struct

```
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

% check to ensure that img exists in handles
if isfield(handles,'img')

    % copy the image from the handles structure
    im=handles.img;

    % continue with your code
    hsv = rgb2hsv(im);

    % etc.

end
```

And that is it - the first callback saves the image to the `handles` structure as a field within it, and the second callback retrieves that image from `handles` via the `img` field.

Try it out and see what happens!

Comment: the second part is seperate matlab file .. and i want to pass the path of browsed image (which is done by pushbutton1) to my another matlab file through push button2.

Comment: plzz help as soon as possible

Comment: So rather than `handles.img = imread(fullimagefilename);` in the pushbutton1 callback, do `handles.imgFilename = fullimagefilename;` instead.

Comment: can i create the above program by uging neural network . basically i need to know how to do image restoration through `neural network` in matlab